# Read xml to arrayList

Tags: c#, xml

I have a problem with reading  XML file. I find out that the reader can read only one customer from the XML file. How can I change
 my code to be allowed to read several customers from XML and store all
 of them to the CustomerList.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CustomerList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <customers>
    <Customer>
      <Name>Sergii</Name>
      <Surname>Liuk</Surname>
      <MobNumber>26397299</MobNumber>
      <CprNumber>1012853463</CprNumber>
      <Email>sergiiliuk@yahoo.dk</Email>
      <Password>3333</Password>
    </Customer>
    <Customer>
      <Name>Sergii</Name>
      <Surname>Liuk</Surname>
      <MobNumber>26397299</MobNumber>
      <CprNumber>343</CprNumber>
      <Email>sergiiliuk@yahoo.dk</Email>
      <Password>66</Password>
    </Customer>
  </customers>
</CustomerList>



CustomerList customers = new CustomerList();

Customer customer;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                
       try
       {
             System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomerList));
             System.IO.TextReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("d:Customer_register.xml");
             customers = (CustomerList)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

             reader.Close();
             lbl_result.Text = "Data Read Successful";
        }
        catch
        {
             lbl_result.Text = "Reading Fail";
        }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    [Serializable]
    public class CustomerList
    {
       public List<Customer> customers;

        public CustomerList()
        {
             customers = new List<Customer>();

        }
        public void addCustomer(Customer customer)
        {
             customers.Add(customer);

        }

    }
}
```

that's how i trying to add a new customer:

```
CustomerList csl = new CustomerList();
            csl.customers = new List<Customer>();
          Customer  customer = new Customer()
            {

                Name = name_text.Text,
                Surname = surname_text.Text,
                MobNumber = int.Parse(mob_text.Text),
                CprNumber = int.Parse(cpr_text.Text),
                Email = email_text.Text,
                Password = password_text.Text

            };

            csl.customers.Add(customer);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                xs.Serialize(ms, csl);
                File.WriteAllBytes("D:temp.xml", ms.ToArray());
            }
```

Comment: Why you want to use ArrayList if you already have CustomerList?

Comment: It may be a problem related to the serializing attributes decorating the `CustomerList`.

Comment: my mistake, i wrote wrong. I need store it to the Customer List

Comment: Can you post the xml format with 2 customers?

Comment: yes, check it please now

Answer (score 2):

Customer List Class ->

```
public class CustomerList
    {
        public List<Customer> customers { get; set; }
    }
```

Customer Class ->

```
 [Serializable]
    public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string MobNumber { get; set; }
        public string CprNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Serialization:

```
  CustomerList csl = new CustomerList();
                csl.customers = new List<Customer>();
                Customer cs = new Customer();
    csl.customers.Add(cs);
  XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(CustomerList));
            using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                xs.Serialize(ms, csl);
                File.WriteAllBytes("temp.xml", ms.ToArray());
            }
```

Deserializarion:

```
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("XMLFile1.xml")))
            {
               csl =  xs.Deserialize(ms) as CustomerList;
                File.WriteAllBytes("temp.xml", ms.ToArray());
            }
```

With Memory Stream we can easily Deserialize.

Now In you case I think you have xml as string , so we can desrialize as below :

```
 using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    writer.Write(File.ReadAllText("XMLFile1.xml")); /// replace here with the xml string
                    writer.Flush();
                    stream.Position = 0;
                    csl = xs.Deserialize(stream) as CustomerList;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!! one more question, How I can after I Deserializing a XML file add a new customer and make a serializing again. I tried it by myself , but i just getting overwriting  a previous data in the XML Thanks for advise.

Comment: You'd better ask another question all together. SO is no discussion board, where a one thing leads to another. If this answer solvbed your problem, mark it.
If you have another issue, feel free to open up a new one.